# Preview not showing in Android studio 3.1.4

Tags: android, error-handling, build, aapt2

Preview not showing in Android studio 3.1.4 but when I change 28.0.0-rc01 to 28.0.0-alpha1 preview works but shows build fail error it didn't goes even when I change it back to 28.0.0-rc01 instead showing Aapt2 error:
I am new I Android studio please fix it for me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Please use any layout other than ConstraintLayout. constraintLayout doesn't have support in sdk version 28.

Answer (score 0):

Please change (`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3`)  or (`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02`) to (`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1`) in build.gradle (Module: App).

Next click File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Need internet access.

It works for me Windows 10 Android studio 3.1.4 and in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Android studio 3.1.4

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 3.2 this bug solved.